# can't get facebook profile pic from flask-OAuth package

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, flask-oauthlib

I am using [this](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth/blob/master/example/facebook.py) code for logging in to my app. It works fine, but when I try to get the url for profile pic

```
pic = facebook.get("/me/picture?fields=url")
```

I get None in response.

```
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None
```

If I try sending this GET request from facebook Graph API, with same access-token, I get the profile link.

[image]

I checked out the version message by printing out get("/me") request, I get

> ```
> connection: keep-alive
> etag: "2c59a2baef08156f18055c64eaa9d9822e35e8f1"
> pragma: no-cache
> cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
> date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 14:20:04 GMT
> **facebook-api-version: v2.9**
> access-control-allow-origin: *
> content-type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
> ```

Which shows that version is automatically converting when i send request from flask-OAuth as well. Then what is it that I am missing ?

Comment: As the documentation says, this endpoint returns a _redirect_ to the user’s profile picture on Facebook’s CDN by default; if you want JSON returned, you need to add the extra parameter it mentions. (Graph API Explorer handles that differently, and always shows JSON, even without the parameter.)

Comment: where do I have to add extra parameters ? Can you point out to the document, where it is mentioned. I tried to search, but couldn't find.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture

Comment: I just did it... was reading this article. and I put redirect=false in my query and finally got the response. But why down vote ?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the Graph API, "me/picture?" will return a 302 redirect to the picture image. To get access to the data about the picture, we need to include redirect=false in the end of query. So I get the url by;

```
pic = facebook.get('/me/picture?redirect=false').data
print 'picture:', pic['data']["url"]
```